# I/O python: Handling output and variable

Tags: python, io

Good day :)

So during the day, I decided to make a gambling simulation. I'm testing a fail gambling strategy (So mine you if you try to tried my method)

Let me show my code, then the whole thing what happened.

```
from random import randint
winningNumber=0
bankroll=5000
testCase=1
betLevel=0
bettingLevel=[1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987]
town=[]
bet=0
#----------------------------
my_file= open("output.txt","w")

my_file.write(" # Bet Number Outcome bankroll "+"\n")
def startTheSimulation():
    print "OK"
    for i in range(100):
        if bankroll==0:
            break
        global betLevel
        if bankroll < bettingLevel[betLevel]:
            betLevel=0
        bet= bettingLevel[betLevel]
        print "betlevel",betLevel
        print "bet",bet
        winningNumber= randint(0,36)
        print "winningnumber",winningNumber
        if winningNumber== 4:
            win(bet)
        else:
            lose(bet)

def win(inbox):
    global bankroll
    cow= inbox*35
    bankroll+=cow
    print "OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"
    print "bankroll",bankroll
    town=[testCase,bet,winningNumber,"WIN",bankroll]
    print town
    betLevel=0
    writing()

def lose(inbox):
    global bankroll
    global betLevel
    wow= inbox
    bankroll-=wow
    town=[testCase,bet,winningNumber,"LOSE",bankroll]
    betLevel+=1
    if betLevel==16:
        betLevel=15
    writing()

def writing():
    global testCase
    testCase+=1
    print "Hey!"
    my_file.write(" ".join(town)+"\n")

startTheSimulation()
my_file.write("On all betting, player bet single bet on one number, which is number 4. How money money bet on number for is indicated.")
my_file.close()
```

My betting system is a weird one. It works like martingale betting system, but instead of doubling my bet, my next bet is based on Fibonacci sequence.

The parameter betLevel is used to decide how many should I bet. The bettingLevel shows the list of the Fibonnaci sequence.

Here comes trouble

Trouble #1:
My output contains blank line

The desired output file is this

```
 & Bet Number Outcome bankroll 
# 100 lines of information
On all betting, player bet single bet on one number, which is number 4. How money money bet on number for is indicated.
```

However, I in turn got this

```
 & Bet Number Outcome bankroll 
# 100 BLANK LINES
On all betting, player bet single bet on one number, which is number 4. How money money bet on number for is indicated.
```

My debugging process:
I actually print the list town. The list if filled (not empty). No other improvement.

Trouble #2: (Solved by using function with arguments.)
My bank roll doesn't update.

My debugging process:
I figured out the problem.

Notice the win function. When I print (int(35)*int(bet)). It turns out to return 0, causing the bankroll not moving.
HOWEVER
When I print "bet",bet in the startTheSimulation() function, it prints the right number. I'm stucked here.

---

That's my 2 biggest problem. Any help is appreciated.

PS: I use global to avoid UnBoundLocalError
PPS: I use Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 1):

Your logic seems quite convoluted for a fairly simple process. Also, you write things like `int(35)`, that tell me you just came to Python from another language (IDL, perhaps?).

If you are using this as an exercise to learn, I can give you a few hints on how to solve it:

First of all, global variables are almost always a bad idea. If you need to use one, you are probably doing something wrong. The proper way of sharing this information is creating a class. Something like this (very incomplete)

```
class Simulation(object):
    def __init__(self, bankroll):
        self.betlevel = 0
        self.betting = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5] # You should actually generate this on the fly
        self.bankroll = bankroll
        self.outputfile = open('filename.txt', 'w')

    def do_bet(self):
        self.bet = self.betting[self.betlevel]
        luckynumber = random.randint()
        mynumber = random.randint()
        if mynumber == luckynumber:
               self.win()

    def win(self):
        self.bankroll -= self.bet
        self.outputfile.write('I won:' + str(self.bet))
```

The idea is that the class methods have access to the class attributes, so you totally avoid global variables, and reduce the possibility of mistake.

Try to complete the implementation. Once you have it, you can post it again and we can see if there are improvements.

Comment: I solved the second problem (The bankroll ) using parameters on fuction, but fail to resolve the output. I honestly haven't learned class yet. I will try to approach it. BTW, please give commend on the new method :) BTW, I came from AS3

Answer (score 0):

**Trouble #1:**
you didn't set `town` as global, so this will print correctly:

```
town=[testCase,bet,winningNumber,"WIN",bankroll]
print town
```

, but in `writing()` method `town` is empty, and that's why you get 100 empty lines

here is example:

```
    #global town #uncomment if you want to change "town" in "one()"
    town = ["not", "changed", "town"]
    def one():
        #global town #uncomment if you want to change "town" here
        town = [1,"local", "town", True]
        print "local -> ", town
    def two():
        # you don't need "global town" here because you do not change it, you only use it
        print town

one()
two()
```

this is output:

```
local ->  [1, 'local', 'town', True]
['not', 'changed', 'town']
```

**Trouble #2:**
similar as trouble #1, in `startTheSimulation():` you need to write `global bet` , otherwise `bet`  is local variable and never gets changed, that's why it's 0 in your  `win()` method.

Those are solutions for your problems , but consider creating a class, like @davidmh said...global variables are almost always a bad idea

Comment: Thank you for the round-a-round solution. I have a hard time learning Class (And unfortunately, I had also bad time with Class in AS3). Thanks once again!